# Avoid looking into Post content while searching

Tags: wordpress

I have created a query using WP_Query for searching posts. Below is the query

```
$args = array(
    's' => 'Keyword'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But the argument 's' always looks into post_title and post_content. I want to change it so it look into post_title only and not into post_content. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first you need to modify the search function of wp, using `posts_search` filter hook Check this [Link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11822/how-to-limit-search-to-post-titles/11826), then run your query and argument.
After that, you need to remove that hook after use.
The example code is bellow

```
<?php
function wpse_11826_search_by_title( $search, $wp_query ) {
    if ( ! empty( $search ) && ! empty( $wp_query->query_vars['search_terms'] ) ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
        $n = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';

        $search = array();

        foreach ( ( array ) $q['search_terms'] as $term )
            $search[] = $wpdb->prepare( "$wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE %s", $n . $wpdb->esc_like( $term ) . $n );

        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
            $search[] = "$wpdb->posts.post_password = ''";

        $search = ' AND ' . implode( ' AND ', $search );
    }

    return $search;
}

add_filter( 'posts_search', 'wpse_11826_search_by_title', 10, 2 );

$args = array(
    's' => 'Keyword'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

remove_filter( 'posts_search', 'wpse_11826_search_by_title', 500 );


//Then your code goes here....


?>
```

Comment: ..and you should credit the original answer... https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11822/how-to-limit-search-to-post-titles/11826

Comment: I am very sorry for this, I have edited my ans. Please check

Comment: After many hours of research and millions of tests this was the only result that worked for me